# Print response json in jmeter using beanshell

Tags: jmeter

I want print my json response in jmeter. I used beanshell but it shows error. Below is the line to print json object extracted in "data":

```
log.info("========"+${data});
```

Comment: Did you get any exceptions or what is the code you are trying to run actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't ever inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into scripts, they may resolve into something which will cause compilation/interpretation failure, use code-based equivalents instead or pass functions/variables via "Parameters" section.

   - Exhibit A: using `vars` shorthand

     ```
     log.info("========" + vars.get("data"));
     ```
   - Exhibit B: using "Parameters" section

     [image: JMeter Beanshell Print Variable]
2. Using Beanshell isn't the best scripting option, consider migrating to [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as Beanshell has known performance problems. Moreover, Groovy has [built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)  See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for details.
3. And finally your `${data}` variable might not be defined (i.e. your extractor fails), in this case you will get interpretation failure on attempt to refer it as `${data}`, double check its value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

Comment: Can I call a disable http request from JSR223?